# sublimetext keyboard shortcut to view recent files

Tags: sublimetext3

Is there any keyboard shortcut in SublimeText which I can use or map to bring down the open files list as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: e]

I know I can view it on the sidebar on the left hand side, but I'm looking for a keyboard shortcut to bring the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You can do "Ctrl+P" for that. That will work on Ubuntu at least. It will show you the list of recently opened files along with the search box to navigate to any other file.

Comment: thanks for that, but is there a specific shortcut I can use to pull down that dropdown shown above?

Comment: There's no direct way to open that particular drop down that I'm aware of; about the best you can is install a plugin that presents the same list of files for you in a quick panel or a different pop up menu instead.